# Loop through array in bind parameters - prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am writing a function in which I can do a couple of database actions, in this case an insert data based on a simple array

```
"insert" => array (
    "1" => array (
        "tnt_role" => array (
            "rolename" => array (
                "value" => "administrator",
                "notation" => "string"
            )
        )
    ),  
    "2" => array (
        "tnt_role" => array (
            "rolename" => array (
                "value" => "user",
                "notation" => "string"
            )
        )
    ),
    "3" => array (  
        "tnt_users" => array (
            "username" => array (
                "value" => "administrator",
                "notation" => "string"
            ),
            "userpassword" => array (
                "value" => md5('admin', FALSE),
                "notation" => "string"
            ),
            "email" => array (
                "value" => "someone@something.com",
                "notation" => "string"
            ),
            "roleid" => array (
                "value" => "1",
                "notation" => "int"
            )
        )
    )   
)
```

and here is the specific part of the function

```
case "insert":
    foreach ($tables as $instance => $inserttables) {
        foreach ($inserttables as $table => $fields) {
            // create a count on the number of fields that are being parsed
            $countfields = count($fields);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ". $table ." (" ;
            $i = 0;
            // set up the columns for the insert statement
            foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {     
                $i++;
                $sql .= $field;
                if ($countfields != $i ) {
                    $sql .= ", ";
                }
            }
            // close the column statement, open the value statement, since this is prepared, we will add question marks and add later the values
            $sql .= ") ";
            $sql .= "VALUES (";
            $i = 0;
            $parameters = "";
            $notation = "";
            foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {     
                $i++;
                $sql .= "?";
                // set up the notation in the bind parameters
                switch($value['notation']) {
                    case "int":
                        $notation .= "i";
                        break;
                    case "string":
                        $notation .= "s"    ;
                        break;  
                }
                // need to escape the email and username values 
                $parameters .= "'".$value['value']."'" ;
                if ($countfields != $i ) {
                    $sql .= ", ";
                    $parameters .= ", ";
                }
            }
            $sql .= ")";

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $notation, $parameters);
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                    echo "data entered";
            } else {
                echo "error in following query:". $sql; 
            }                               
        }
    }
    break;
```

This works all fine except for 1 tiny thing and that is when I enter more than 1 item in the database. It gives me the following error

> mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string
> doesn't match number of bind variables in .... line 647

I realized after a while that it is the **parameter** variable that is the case. The bind parameter here is only 1 variable in which I separate it all nicely with a comma (in order to mimic the list). Viewing this optical would say this looks fine, however I think the bind parameter statement really requires separate variables. At this point it sees actually just one variable, rather than the 4 in my test case.

I tried looping it this way:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $notation, 
    foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {     
        echo $value['value'];
        if ($countfields != $i ) {
            echo ",";
        }
    }
);
```

But to no avail, since it will spit out the following.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

== edit ==

table structure as requested, although I doubt it is that problem, since I get a bind parameter error, not an error in executing the statement.

[image: structure of this table]

== edit 2 ==

also tried the following, which didn't help, since it didn't stack (I saw this in PDO)

```
foreach ($fields as $field => $value) { 
    switch($value['notation']) {
        case "int":
            $notation = "i";
            break;
        case "string":
            $notation = "s" ;
            break;  
    }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $notation, $value['value']);
}
```

Comment: What does your database structure look like?

Comment: This has nothing to do with my database, its pure that part, since i can fill my roles table without any problem (its just an id and a description and then i enter simply ust the description). If you must know, i added a picture of it's structure, very simple at this point @gview

Comment: On a side note, it would be easier for you to use PDO or even something better like a DB abstraction class, e.g. EasyDB.

Comment: I would strongly advice to take a look at some of the tutorials on https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple They explain how to use mysqli properly if you are already stuck with it.

Comment: added the link to my collection, @Dharman

Comment: Are you really using MD5 for password hashing/storage?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner at this moment, yes, since i am doing this all locally on my own wamp. I still need to write the code for hashing and salting it propperly. That, is not my greatest concern at this point. I am well aware of the weakness of md5

Comment: Ok. Look into [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and the related links in there. There is also no need to salt, it takes care of all that. Plus, if you're on PHP 7, you can benefit from using Argon2 which is even more powerful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass each variable individually to [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param), so `$parameters` needs to be an array, not a string. Change the following lines of code:

```
$parameters = "";
```

to:

```
$parameters = array();
```

and

```
$parameters .= "'".$value['value']."'" ;
```

to:

```
$parameters[] = $value['value'];
```

(note there is no need to escape values when you are using prepared statements)

remove this line:

```
$parameters .= ", ";
```

and finally, change

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $notation, $parameters);
```

to:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $notation, ...$parameters);
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: @Dharman I spent a lot of time looking for a duplicate but couldn't find one - do you have a good link?

Comment: No, my collection of links is very small. I am not a fan of forcibly closing questions as duplicates.

Comment: @Dharman I'm with you but had an argument with someone earlier about that very thing - there's definitely two schools of thought about it on the site.

Comment: @Nick thank you very much for this solution, It does indeed the trick. Can you explain what the periods are before the parameter variable? I never seen this. I knew somewhere an array could be passed, but i had no idea how to access it, this is obviously the solution for my problem. I accepted it as awnser.

Comment: @Dorvalla the periods are the `splat` operator. It can be used to assemble arrays but also to unpack them into an argument list. There's more information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)